# Haskell: parse error on input '='

Tags: haskell, implementation, haskell-platform

I keep gettin this message, what am i doing wrong?

```
data Pile a =  Pile [a] deriving  (Show,Eq,Ord)  

flpile:: (Eq a, Eq b, Eq c) => Pile (a,(b,c))-> Pile (a,b,c)
flpile (Pile (a,(b,c)) = Pile [asocr (a,(b,c))]

asocr :: (a,(b,c)) -> (a,b,c)
asocr (a,(b,c)) = (a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in this line

```
flpile (Pile (a,(b,c)) = Pile [asocr (a,(b,c))]
```

you forgot a closing brace at **(** Pile (a,(b,c)) **)**

When you correct that, you'll get an error. That's because the `(a,(b,c))` is not a list, as your data definition says. I don't know, what you want to achieve with your code, but you could change it to `Pile [(a,(b,c))]`, so it will compile (if that makes any sense for your purpose).

Comment: Thanks, it worked,i'm a noob in haskell trying to implement a stack, with some useful functions.

Answer (score 7):

You have a mismatched parenthesis:

```
flpile (Pile (a,(b,c))) = ...
                      ^ this was missing
```

To avoid this problem in the future, I recommmend enabling the "highlight matching brackets" option in your editor, if there is one. If not, get a better editor.

Comment: God Im dumb haha, thanks, i get another kind of error message now,

Comment: @user2278354: Right. A `Pile` is supposed to contain a list, but your pattern has a tuple. What is the function supposed to do with the list? Apply the same transformation to all items?

Comment: yeah, the function changes the association of the elements. I made it work already